# position and resize a local image

Tags: markdown

I would like to know how to position and resize an image, I tried several command but none of them works. I export my document in pdf.

With this command the image is placed all at the bottom of the page

```
![img](pathImg)
```

To resize the image I do that but it does not work

```
![img](pathImg =100x20)
![img](pathImg { width: 200px; }
```

The html command does not work when I export in pdf

```
<img src="pathImg" alt="img" style="width: 200px;"/>
```

Comment: what markdown engine do you use?

Comment: i don't know where i see what markdown engine i have. I have install markdown from Rstudio.

Comment: if you're using `R Markdown v2` then it's using pandoc under the hood. if so, you can use `![img](pathImg){width=200px}`

Comment: Hello, when i use the command _![img](pathImg){width=450px}_ either the image takes a whole page or the image goes to the top of the page, my image has a size of 468x271